# How to match and remove the content preceding it from a file in unix

Tags: mysql, perl, sed, solaris

I have a mysql dump file, and i want to remove the content of the file after "-- Final view structure for view `view_oss_user`" using sed/perl. 
The input file is something like this :
Content :

```
rom `target` */;
/*!50001 SET character_set_client      = @saved_cs_client */;
/*!50001 SET character_set_results     = @saved_cs_results */;
/*!50001 SET collation_connection      = @saved_col_connection */;

--
-- Final view structure for view `view_oss_user`
--

/*!50001 DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `view_oss_user`*/;
/*!50001 SET @saved_cs_client          = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50001 SET @saved_cs_results         = @@character_set_results */;
/*!50001 SET @saved_col_connection     = @@collation_connection */;
/*!50001 SET character_set_client      = latin1 */;
/*!50001 SET character_set_results     = latin1 */;
```

And the output should be like below :

```
rom `target` */;
    /*!50001 SET character_set_client      = @saved_cs_client */;
    /*!50001 SET character_set_results     = @saved_cs_results */;
    /*!50001 SET collation_connection      = @saved_col_connection */;

    --
```

Comment: it is not clear what you want here. Provide a more clear sample of input, desired output and, of course, what you tried so far.

Comment: Please show your code and describe the problems you are having with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with GNU sed

```
sed -n '1,/-- Final view structure for view `view_oss_user`/p'
```

this will print lines from 1 till pattern found, others will not be printed

or if you want to exclude pattern line then

```
sed -n '1,/-- Final view structure for view `view_oss_user`/p' | sed '$d'
```

Comment: how should i give the file as an input., i tried : cat /tmp/caa_dump.sql | sed -n '1,/-- Final view structure for view view_oss_user/p' > /tmp/new_test.sql   but it is stil printing the whole content

Comment: looks good, check entered pattern (one character can blown it). If you know where is that line, print it to be sure

Comment: but you can also use sed -n '1,/pattern/p' <inputfile >outputfile

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @new_dump;
my $flag = 0;

while(<DATA>)
{
   if ( m/-- Final view structure for view `view_oss_user`/ )
   {
      $flag++;
   }
   push @new_dump, $_ unless $flag > 0;
}

print Dumper( \@new_dump );

__DATA__
rom `target` */;
/*!50001 SET character_set_client      = @saved_cs_client */;
/*!50001 SET character_set_results     = @saved_cs_results */;
/*!50001 SET collation_connection      = @saved_col_connection */;

--
-- Final view structure for view `view_oss_user`
--

/*!50001 DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `view_oss_user`*/;
/*!50001 SET @saved_cs_client          = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50001 SET @saved_cs_results         = @@character_set_results */;
/*!50001 SET @saved_col_connection     = @@collation_connection */;
/*!50001 SET character_set_client      = latin1 */;
/*!50001 SET character_set_results     = latin1 */;
```

Run it:

```
 ./perl 
$VAR1 = [
          'rom `target` */;
',
          '/*!50001 SET character_set_client      = @saved_cs_client */;
',
          '/*!50001 SET character_set_results     = @saved_cs_results */;
',
          '/*!50001 SET collation_connection      = @saved_col_connection */;
',
          '
',
          '--
'
        ];
```